# Vue Cli - npm run serve ERROR - Module not found

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuex, web-development-server

I've got a problem while running

```
npm run serve
```

command after initializing new project with Vue Cli.
Error looks like this:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                          08:42:28

error

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<project folder>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.18.103&port=8081&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in '<project folder>'

ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<project folder>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.18.103&port=8081&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in '<project folder>'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Also after running

```
npm install
```

after initialization i have an error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-vue@8.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-vue@"^8.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!   dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!     dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Running the command with *--force* or *--legacy-peer-deps* doesn't help at all.

I have:

- **npm** version 9.5.1
- **nodeJS** version 18.14.2
- **vue/cli** version 5.0.8

I tried reinstalling webpack-dev-server extension, deleting and reinstalling node_modules folder and many more. No effect :/ Still the same error.

I'd like to finally run my Vue dev server and get to work.

Comment: Did you try downgrading nodejs? I had some issues with v18 and didn't bother trying to resolve it. If this is a personal project, it might resolve your issue.

Comment: Yeah i tried. From v. 16.11 to current one

Comment: and you removed lock and node_modules?

Comment: The problem is already solved.
It has been a problem with a project directory (no idea what problem, maybe path? maybe names?).
When I placed a project in different directory it worked with no problems :)

Answer (score -1):

how about trying to uninstall vue/cli and reinstall vue/cli?

Comment: I tried also this. Many times

Answer (score -1):

try it
npm i --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: I tried and still the same error